# How to Create the Sub theme for the bootstrap 7.x-3.6 in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

using the bootstrap 7.x-3.6 in drupal 7. Guide me how to create the sub-theme.
I am getting following errors.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: navbar_classes in include() (line 76 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: container_class in include() (line 77 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: container_class in include() (line 117 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: content_column_class in include() (line 135 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: container_class in include() (line 169 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: html_attributes in include() (line 57 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\html.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: body_attributes in include() (line 71 of C:\xampp\htdocs\Drupal\sites\all\themes\Indivar\templates\html.tpl.php).
```

Comment: You should provide more information about what you did before you get these errors and what you tried to fix the problem so far : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using the bootstrap  7.x-3.6 and then create a subtheme in the directory sites->all-> theme->subtheme.
then copy the page.tpl and html.tpl in the template folder under the subtheme and add the info file in the sub theme. When we enable the subtheme then got these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename .info file in the subtheme folder as as well..

This should be the folder structure

/sites/all/themes/bootstrap

/sites/all/themes/subtheme_name

/sites/all/themes/subtheme_name/subtheme_name.info